# mathematically represent a percentage of time without local storage

Tags: javascript, math, percentage

Is there way to reliably execute a function a certain percentage of time without using local storage?

eg: On page load, console.log('hello') 60% of the time.

1. Create a random number between 1-10
2. If number == 7,8,9, or 10 don't execute
3. Otherwise, console.log('hello);

If each number has an equal probability of being selected, running a function when 6 of the 10 numbers are chosen = 60% run time.

Is something like this mathematically sound? Cookies and sessions aren't available..

Thanks

Update: I'm not looking for the code to do it. I'm asking about the math.

Comment: Yes, it totally makes sense - however it is not clear what would be the use of this; is this simply out of interest and for learning purposes or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried calling `Math.random()` and if the resulting number is less than `0.6`, log Hello?

Comment: You mean like `if (Math.random() < 0.6) {console.log("Hello World")}`?

Comment: If something has the probability of running 6 out of 10 times, and you run it 10 times, there is no certainty that it will run 6 times.

Comment: Yes it is this mathematically sound but as with any probability, you will need to repeat it many times to achieve a true 60%. E.g. consider flipping a coin twice, there is a good chance it will land on the same side both times, however if you do it 100 times it will even out to roughly 50/50.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(Math.random() < 0.6) {
    console.log('hello')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
var display = rand < 7;

if (display) {
    console.log('hello');
}
```

No local storage needed. All you need is plain old JS.

**NOTE**: You could actually simplify `display` down to just `Math.random() < 0.7` but I thought I'd write out the steps to make the logic easier to follow, especially since `Math.random()` produces floating point numbers and the question was dealing with whole numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var number = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
if (number < 7) doSomething();
```

This seems to be what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use function composition to make a function that sometimes will invoke a callback function.

```
function maybeCallback(callback) {
    function shouldCallback() {
        // 60% chance
        return Math.random() < 0.6;
    }

    return function () {
        if(shouldCallback()) {
            callback();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
function callback() {
    console.log('This might get called');
}

var maybeCallable = maybeCallback(callback);

setTimeout(maybeCallable, 1000);
```

As for the math side take a look at [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

> returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range [0, 1)
>   that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive),
>   which you can then scale to your desired range.

The percentage `W` of an exclusive range `R` (`[X, Y)`) from a value `Z` is defined by:

[image: W = (Z-X)/(Y-X)*100]

Given the values:

[image: W = (0.6-0)/(1-0)*100 = 0.6/1*100 = 60%]